# Scrolling ScrollView even when ContentView has the same size

Tags: swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have a ScrollView defined with autolayout : it has a contentView, in which there's some elements. The scrollView has constraints with other views to set it's size, and 4 constraints with the contentView (up, down, left, right, each with constant = 0). The contentView has a defined size, the same size as the scrollView.

I want my scrollView to scroll and bounce (I overrided the scrollViewDidScroll method), but the problem is the scrollView is not scrolling if the contentView has the same size as it (which is logic, since there's no content to scroll, but I want it to bounce).

How can I make my scrollView scrolling ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting to your `scrollView`:

```
scrollView.alwaysBounceHorizontal = true
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
```

or in Interface Builder, make sure you've checked options:

[image: IB]